# Why token secret is returned unecrypted in OAUTH?

Tags: oauth

My understanding of the 'key' (or 'token') in OAUTH system is like a 'username' to identify the sender which is not confidential but 'secret' is actually like a 'password'.

But reading through the OAUTH 1.0 spec on http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process, it seems to me when ***consumer*** asks ***service provider*** for a token (either request token or access token) , **the token and token secret are returned in PLAIN (just base-64 encoded) text** as HTTP response.

And after searching web it looks in lots of not all case, the "request token URL" is HTTP not HTTPS which means **a 3rd party may intercept the token and token secret**.

So am I wrong thus far? I know even a 3rd party intercepted the token secret it's still useless as any request by consumer (or any party claim as the consumer) must be signatured with consumer key (plus token secrect) which the 3rd party usually don't know, but then why we need the token secret then?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is *permitted* to use http, it is *recommended* (see appendix B.1) to use secure transport (https), otherwise your concerns are quite valid. I know for sure Google allows https:// on all their OAuth transactions, at least as far as getting the token and secret, and for all the API data requests that I've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, a further dummy question -- any idea why OAUTH doesn't use the consumer secret to encrypt the token secret? it seems not going to add a lot burden to service provider as the token/token secret size is not big.

Comment: good point. but then, oauth2 makes even the signature optional, so TLS is the only security employed at all. from what I've read, the more security-minded people were drummed out of the OAuth decision-making.